# Sort events in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to intercept the range sort event? For example when user select a range, select sort range, click on sort, I need intercept the sort event. The business problem that I am trying to resolve is, if user doesn't include a particular col for sort, I want to either warn the user or include the required col in the sort.

Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible.  The events you can use to trigger an Apps Script are quite limited, and they don't behave the way traditional Javascript events do, because they run on the server, not in the users browser.  Even if a Sort event was made available, your code likely wouldn't be triggered until the default action was completed and the sorting finished.

You could experiment with the Edit event, that will be triggered any time the spreadsheet values are edited, which may include sorting (I've never tested this).  But as I mentioned above, you can't block the edit from occurring, just respond to it's results.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Answer (score 0):

You could tie the sort you would like to performed to a custom button or script menu command, but you cannot captue a sort event or even disable sort in any sheet where a user has edit rights.

To create a button, follow Insert > Drawing, make a shape (rounded rectangle recommended), save it on the sheet, and use the drawing's drop down menu to assign the script by its name.

Comment: Or better yet use a menu. Clickable drawings have drawbacks like not being able to freeze rows where a drawing is.

Comment: True. I tend to have them there in sheet headers if at all but while I prefer using menu commands people are idiots and sometimes need the big red button to press before they work out they have to do. And even then....